# How to putting clearfix after third div?

Tags: html, css

I have boxes which size is 33.33% that is why 3 boxes are making 100% totaly.when I added fourth div and my 4th div is slipping whenever I putted .clearfix my problem is over..but I want to put clearfix every each 3rd div
thanks.
ok.. @AndreiGheorghiu my codes;

```css
.ref-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 3.3% 10px 0;
}
.ref-item {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 7px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: rgba(242, 102, 81, .8);
}
.ref-box figure a img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.ref-box:nth-child(3n+3):after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="ref-box">
  <figure>
    <a href="works/Facebook/index.html" title="created html-css" target="_blank">
      <img src="works/Facebook/thumbnail.jpg" height="451" width="500" alt="Facebook Clone" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
  </figure>
  <div class="ref-item">
    <span class="ref-head">Facebook Clone</span>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- every ref item-->
```

copy this code more than one and see the result

Comment: [`{clear:both;}`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp) on the element you want on new line. Or use `<br style="clear: both;" />` inline.

Comment: I know clear:both; but problem is every each 3rd div and with css may be we can do with nth selectors :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.parent>.child:nth-child(3n) {
    clear: both;
}
```

---

UPDATE, after question being completed:

Your clearfix is working fine. Here:

```css
.ref-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 3.3% 10px 0;
}
.ref-item {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 7px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: rgba(242, 102, 81, .8);
}
.ref-box figure a img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.ref-box:nth-child(3n+3):after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ref-box">
  <figure>
    <a href="works/Facebook/index.html" title="created html-css" target="_blank">
      <img src="works/Facebook/thumbnail.jpg" height="451" width="500" alt="Facebook Clone" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
  </figure>
  <div class="ref-item">
    <span class="ref-head">Facebook Clone</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ref-box">
  <figure>
    <a href="works/Facebook/index.html" title="created html-css" target="_blank">
      <img src="works/Facebook/thumbnail.jpg" height="451" width="500" alt="Facebook Clone" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
  </figure>
  <div class="ref-item">
    <span class="ref-head">Facebook Clone</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ref-box">
  <figure>
    <a href="works/Facebook/index.html" title="created html-css" target="_blank">
      <img src="works/Facebook/thumbnail.jpg" height="451" width="500" alt="Facebook Clone" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
  </figure>
  <div class="ref-item">
    <span class="ref-head">Facebook Clone</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ref-box">
  <figure>
    <a href="works/Facebook/index.html" title="created html-css" target="_blank">
      <img src="works/Facebook/thumbnail.jpg" height="451" width="500" alt="Facebook Clone" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
  </figure>
  <div class="ref-item">
    <span class="ref-head">Facebook Clone</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ref-box">
  <figure>
    <a href="works/Facebook/index.html" title="created html-css" target="_blank">
      <img src="works/Facebook/thumbnail.jpg" height="451" width="500" alt="Facebook Clone" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
  </figure>
  <div class="ref-item">
    <span class="ref-head">Facebook Clone</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ref-box">
  <figure>
    <a href="works/Facebook/index.html" title="created html-css" target="_blank">
      <img src="works/Facebook/thumbnail.jpg" height="451" width="500" alt="Facebook Clone" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
  </figure>
  <div class="ref-item">
    <span class="ref-head">Facebook Clone</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="ref-box">
  <figure>
    <a href="works/Facebook/index.html" title="created html-css" target="_blank">
      <img src="works/Facebook/thumbnail.jpg" height="451" width="500" alt="Facebook Clone" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
  </figure>
  <div class="ref-item">
    <span class="ref-head">Facebook Clone</span>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- every ref item-->
```

---

Second update, after seeing the live page. Your problem is you are floating elements of uneven heights.

Updated again, after seeing the live example. Please not I added a custom class (`.makeColumns`) to your `col-md-12` container. I also added this to CSS:

```
.makeColumns {
    -webkit-columns: 300px 3;
    -moz-columns: 300px 3;
    columns: 300px 3;
}
h2 {
   -webkit-column-span: all;
   column-span: all;
}
```

You can see it working here:

```css
.makeColumns {
-webkit-columns: 300px 3;
   -moz-columns: 300px 3;
        columns: 300px 3;
}
h2 {
 -webkit-column-span: all;
         column-span: all;
}


.ref-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 3.3% 10px 0;
}
.ref-item {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 7px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: rgba(242, 102, 81, .8);
}
.ref-box figure a img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.ref-box:nth-child(3n+3):after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="section references" id="references">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 makeColumns">
      <h2 class="head"><i class="fa fa-code"></i> References</h2>
      <!-- <p>
                    This page will be designed soon. for now <a href="works">click here</a> to see his references
                  </p>-->
      <div class="ref-box">
        <figure>
          <a href="works/nartasarim/index.html" title="created with bootstrap" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://cv.firatabak.com/works/nartasarim/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Nar Tasarım" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </figure>
        <div class="ref-item">
          <span class="ref-head">Nar Tasarım</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- every ref item-->

      <div class="ref-box">
        <figure>
          <a href="works/ElZero/index.html" title="created with bootstrap" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://cv.firatabak.com/works/ElZero/thumbnail.jpg" alt="El Zero" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </figure>
        <div class="ref-item">
          <span class="ref-head">El Zero</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- every ref item-->

      <div class="ref-box">
        <figure>
          <a href="works/Singolo/index.html" title="created with bootstrap" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://cv.firatabak.com/works/Singolo/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Singolo" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </figure>
        <div class="ref-item">
          <span class="ref-head">Singolo</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- every ref item-->


      <div class="ref-box">
        <figure>
          <a href="works/Facebook/index.html" title="created html-css" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://cv.firatabak.com/works/Facebook/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Facebook Clone" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </figure>
        <div class="ref-item">
          <span class="ref-head">Facebook Clone</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- every ref item-->

      <div class="ref-box">
        <figure>
          <a href="works/nartasarim/index.html" title="created with bootstrap" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://cv.firatabak.com/works/nartasarim/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Nar Tasarım" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </figure>
        <div class="ref-item">
          <span class="ref-head">Nar Tasarım</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- every ref item-->

      <div class="ref-box">
        <figure>
          <a href="works/nartasarim/index.html" title="created with bootstrap" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://cv.firatabak.com/works/nartasarim/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Nar Tasarım" class="img-responsive">
          </a>
        </figure>
        <div class="ref-item">
          <span class="ref-head">Nar Tasarım</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- every ref item-->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for everything it is working already then.probably my problem is different bkz:http://cv.firatabak.com

Thanks for everything

Comment: I see what your problem is. I'll edit the answer in a minute with your options :)

Comment: Done editing. The best solution when you have random content, that can have any height on any column, is to use CSS columns. See second snippet in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can write css for that like given bellow

```
div:nth-child(3n+3) {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: `display:table` is a hack that I don't personally recommend. Widely spread mainly because of Bootstrap, it was only meant to deal with browser long gone now. Let's just allow code to be correct, shall we? At least when we're teaching. :)

Comment: i'm using bootstrap but the code isn't working for me

Comment: In that case you need to create a [mcve], yedincifirat. @Shree: could you please explain the difference between `:nth-child(3n+3)` and `:nth-child(3n)`? I noticed you changed from second to first. Why?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu (3 x 0) = 0 = no match  (3 x 1) = 3 = 3rd Element  (3 x 2) = 6 = 6th Element (3 x 3) = 9 = 9th Element  So added 3n+3

Comment: Exactly. **Every single CSS rule** in any stylesheet is run against **every single element in the page** and  99% of the time the result is `no match`. It's how CSS works, there's no need to try to avoid it. You're only writing 2 characters of code more, for the same exact result. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `overflow: hidden;`